# What is the difference between Expo and React Native? latest release 2018

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

https://expo.io/

deos react-native using expo internally. can i use the expo-sdk in react-native without need to eject from expo and hust as nom package itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages:

Setting up a project is easy and can be done in minutes
You (and other people) can open the project while you're working on it
Sharing the app is easy (via QR-code or link), you don't have to send the whole .apk or .ipa file
No build necessary to run the app.

Disadvantages:

You can't add native modules (probably a gamechanger for some)
You can't use libraries that use native code in Objective-C/Java
The standard Hello World app is about 25MB big (because of the integrated libraries)
If you want to use: FaceDetector, ARKit o Payments you need to eject it to ExpoKit
Ejecting it to ExpoKit has a trade-off of features of Expo, e.g. you cannot share via QR code
When ejecting to ExpoKit you are limited to the react native version that is supported by ExpoKit at that point in time
Debugging in ExpoKit (with native modules) is a lot more complicated, since it mixes two languages and different libraries (no official Expo support anymore)

This is important because with React Native you can always drop down to native code. This is incredibly helpful sometimes but it comes at a cost: you need to send people your binaries if you want them to test them, someone on the other side of the world can't just tap a link to open it while you're working on it and you can't just publish it with one click for someone to access it similar to how you would in a browser.

Comment: yes. it think it was very useful will go through the link